# Android ImageView being cropped

Tags: android, imageview, scale

first of all here's a graphic to illustrate my problem:
[Graphic](http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-12zjrn.jpg)

On the left image you can see how it should look. And this is also how AndroidStudio shows it in the preview. But if I run it on the emulator, it cropps the image and only the dark green part is left. (right image)

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

The parent view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".menu">
```

I trief different scaleTypes, but nothing gives me the outcome I want to have.
Not the first time I'm sturggling with ImageViews, but the first time I can't solve the issue myself...

If I remove the "adjustViewBounds" the preview shows the same outcome as the device/emulator. In case that that is a hint for someone.

Edit: I created a second version of the header, which is double the size. And now it works with "fitXy" and "adjustViewBound(true)". But why? The original image was 512px in height, which should've been enough for adjustViewBounds to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` will give you that result that you see on the right so remove it

Comment: Then it won't scale at all. It would just cover about the half of the width the screen is providing.

Comment: what was wrong with CENTER_INSIDE?

Comment: centerInside gives me the exact same outcome as if I would use no scaleType at all. So the image would just cover half the space the screen is providing in width.

Comment: and what about fitXY, is the image literally just that green box?  why not just set a background color or use a 9-patch drawable?

Comment: can you post the parent layout in the xml as well?

Comment: No it's not just the green box. I just wanted to hide the original image ;)

Comment: fitXy also looks good in the preview. But on the device itself it's wrong. The "physical size" is the same as with "centerCrop". But the image isn't cropped, but squeezed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want CENTER_INSIDE:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

> public static final ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_INSIDE
>
> Added in API level 1 Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's
>   aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image
>   will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view
>   (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use
>   this syntax: android:scaleType="centerInside".

**also**

The issue may be that adjustViewBounds will not increase the size of the ImageView beyond the natural dimensions of the drawable.

Comment: I already tried that. When using centerInside it won't scale the image. It's just about half the width of the screen.

Comment: interesting.. what is the larger of the two dimensions, width or height?

Comment: can you post the actual image? and the parent view from the layout xml?

Comment: I've added the parent view to my question. Maybe I can post the original image later, currently I don't have access to it.

Comment: I created a second version of the header, which is double the size. And now it works with "fitXy" and "adjustViewBound(true)". But why? The original image was 512px in height, which should've been enough for adjustViewBounds to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: pixels are different than dp.. whats the width/ ratio?

Comment: The resolution was 1512x512px.

Comment: depending on the resolution of the device it might not have been wide enough with adjustViewBounds set to true

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be because the ImageView is not yet fully initialized or sized when you try to set the image. The time it takes to load and render an image in the ViewHolder may vary, especially if the images are large or there are many of them.

Try load images using the Glide, which are good at asynchronous loading and image caching

```
        Glide.with(itemBinding.root)
            .load(imgUrl)
            .error(ColorDrawable(PLACEHOLDER_COLOR))
            .placeholder(ColorDrawable(PLACEHOLDER_COLOR))
            .into(itemBinding.image)
```

instead of ImageView.load() method